# Returning an element value from chrome.tabs to a background script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to send a value from the tab html content to my chrome extension background script.

Right now I'm using a workaround, that is

`chrome.tabs.executeScript()` to send a code to retrieve data and then send it to my web server via Ajax, and then my background script checks to see if its there in my server. But that's obviously not the right way.

Is there a way to get element values and then send it back to the background script? so I can keep working with the value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.extension.sendRequest()` has a counterpart `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener()`

If it's not obvious you can read all about message passing here:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html